# Is Spock still married to T'Pring in the Kelvin timeline?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-2009, spock

In the Original Series episode "Amok Time", Spock reveals that he is married (in an arranged marriage when they were children) to T'Pring. When he undergoes the pon farr, he returns to her, but he releases her from their marriage bond after she initiates a duel to the death with Kirk as her champion.

Is Spock still married to T'Pring in the Kelvin timeline, at least until his first pon farr? Since he's in a relationship with Uhura, that could be interpreted as him being unfaithful to his wife if they were still married.

Answer (score 3):

In the continuity comics ([*Star Trek Ongoing 24 (After Darkness*)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek,_Volume_6:_After_Darkness), we see Kelvin Timeline Spock return to his people. His *betrothed*, T'Pring is present and they prepare to mate.

[image]

A few issue later (and after much kerfuffle but no hanky-panky) he overcomes his Pon Farr and they part as friends rather than as a married couple.

[image]

Comment: Wow, she doesn't look *at all* like [T'Pring from The Original Series](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/2/2d/TPring.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20081213210802&path-prefix=en). I mean, I know that Spock looks different because of a new actor, but I would have expected a comic to keep the likenesses much closer since there is no actor involved.

Comment: It's relevant that she says she is "betrothed", since in Amok Time, Spock described their relationship as "Less than a marriage but more than a betrothal" (and that apparently, "wife" was the best way to describe that in-between state). So one could argue that she is *not* his wife, since they seem to have a less committed relationship in this timeline.

Comment: @Thunderforge - In this continuity, it would appear that they've spent time together, but never mated nor taken their marriage vows.

Comment: Betrothed just means engaged. They may still be so but this comic seems to take place entirely before the wedding - if one happens here.